# MongoDB: How to find Documents that contain information about only latest changes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the application, we already have a mechanism of logging changes that happen in our entities.
For example, we have `Category` and `Product` entities,

where `Category` looks like:

```
Category {
name;
description
}
```

and `Product` looks like:

```
Product {
name;
price; 
quantity
}
```

Currently, we log information when any of the fields of our entities were modified:

Assume, that for `Category` entity
the `name` property was changed twice;
the `description` property was changed 3 times;

and for a `Product` entity
the only `price` property was changed twice.

then in our `LogCollection` we will have the following `Document`s:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "name",
    "changed": "2020-08-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "name",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-29"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "entity": "Product",
    "property": "price",
    "changed": "2020-08-20"
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "entity": "Product",
    "property": "price",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  }
]
```

The problem that I am trying to solve now:

I want to extract only the latest changes per each field for each unique entity.

I mean, that as result of some magic query I will get the following list of Documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "name",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "entity": "Category",
    "property": "description",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  },
  
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "entity": "Product",
    "property": "price",
    "changed": "2020-08-31"
  }
]
```

Those 3 `Documents` show me when exactly the latest changes for entity fields were made per each unique entity.

Could you please support me with a query to get those 3 `Documents`?

For sure, I have already reviewed Mongo DB documentation and found that potentially I have to use aggregation framework with `$group` and `$max` operators, but still I am stuck with writing real working query

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) stage.

First `$match` to limit the number of documents considered, unless you actually want to examine every log document since the beginning of time.
Sort by the `changed` field in descending order, so the newest documents come first.
Group by `entity` and `property`, keeping only the first document encountered.
Use `$replaceRoot` or `$project` to restructure the document the way you need.

Note that the sample data is unable to determine which update came first if 2 happened on the same day.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {}}, //if desired
  {$sort: {changed: -1}}, 
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        property: "$property",
        entity: "$entity"
      },
      document: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$document"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8XJJKjjHbaX)

Answer (score 0):

```
//source data, sort by latest date changed as the first document in the output/collection
> db.logCollection.find().sort({Category:1,property:1,changed:-1});
{ "_id" : 5, "entity" : "Category", "property" : "description", "changed" : "2020-08-31" }
{ "_id" : 4, "entity" : "Category", "property" : "description", "changed" : "2020-08-30" }
{ "_id" : 3, "entity" : "Category", "property" : "description", "changed" : "2020-08-29" }
{ "_id" : 2, "entity" : "Category", "property" : "name", "changed" : "2020-08-31" }
{ "_id" : 1, "entity" : "Category", "property" : "name", "changed" : "2020-08-30" }
{ "_id" : 7, "entity" : "Product", "property" : "price", "changed" : "2020-08-31" }
{ "_id" : 6, "entity" : "Product", "property" : "price", "changed" : "2020-08-20" }
//use sort to reflect latest document first and use $first as shown below
> db.logCollection.aggregate([
... {$sort:{Category:1,property:1,changed:-1}},
... {$group:{_id:{entity: "$entity",
...               property: "$property"},
...   latestChange: {$first:"$changed"}
... }
...   },
... ]);
{ "_id" : { "entity" : "Category", "property" : "name" }, "latestChange" : "2020-08-31" }
{ "_id" : { "entity" : "Product", "property" : "price" }, "latestChange" : "2020-08-31" }
{ "_id" : { "entity" : "Category", "property" : "description" }, "latestChange" : "2020-08-31" }
>
```